# Running PolSARPro 5.0 - How to compile?

Tags: compiling

Hej,
I'am new with Linux and I want to install *PolSARPro*. But I don't know how. I should compile a .bat-file, but I can't find how to do that.
From Install instructions:
*"Before running PolSARpro, Linux Users have to compile the executable processing files.
For this, is provided a batch file, called **Compil_PolSARpro_v5_Linux.bat** located in the Soft
directory."*
Anybody knows how this works?
Thank u!

Comment: Linux does not have batch (.bat) files, as those are scripts for the DOS/Windows command prompt. However, I presume it's actually a shell script, and you just need to run it.

Comment: I've tried that, but without success. I think I have to generate a .sh from the .bat, because further in the instructions: "Once the executable files compiled, create a link between the directory where is installed
PolSARpro software and the sh command to launch PolSARpro, with: `ln –s /my_dir/PolSARpro_v5.0/PolSARpro.sh /usr/bin/PolSARpro`

Comment: Can you provide a link to the installation instructions? Maybe someone here understands them better than you and can clarify them.

Answer (score 0):

The `Compil_PolSARpro_v5_Linux.bat` file is a shell script. You must run it with `sh Compil_PolSARpro_v5_Linux.bat` within the *Soft* sub-directory of the distribution after unpacking it.

The symlink is not absolutely necessary, to run the program. You'll just need to run the *PolSARpro.sh* script with the full path, every time you want to run the program.

The resulting file is in fact a shell script, but it is named `PolSARpro_v5.0.tcl` instead of `PolSARpro.sh`. You'll need to run this file with `sh`. You should probably contact the ESA to report these issues with the software though. They really should make this easier for people to use.

Comment: I've tried that. There is no _PolSARPro.sh_ but a _PolSARpro_v5.0.tcl_ Here is a link to the full instructions: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/oqs4hcji1pnstn8/README_PolSARpro_v5.0_Install_Linux.pdf?dl=0] I don't understand that, because I using Linux since yesterday. Thanks

Comment: The `PolSARpro_v5.0.tcl` file is a shell script.